# Add tracking link to shipment email doesn't work

Tags: email-templates, shipment, shipment-tracking

I've implemented the tracking block in

> System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails -> Shipment -> Shipment Email
>   Template

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Now I want to trigger the email by calling
    `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional()`
 in my code.

But this doesn't work, the tracking information will not show up. I'm wondering if I also have to set the $shipment and $order parameter but `sendTransactional()` doesn't come with these parameter.

The email template will be used - I've already checked this.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!